# As it is correct to impose the interface in android with dynamic addition of elements?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

There was a complexity in implementation of imposition using fragments. 
There is a template on which it is necessary to impose the page.

As I approach the solution of this task:
1) I create MainActivity 
2) I add textView to a marking of MainActivity (for header), linearLayout (for fragments) and textView (for footer).
3) I take place a loop according to data (image id) in MainActivity and create fragments.
Like this:

```
for (int photoId : photoNumbers) {
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        PhotoFragment fragment = PhotoFragment.newInstance();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putLong("id", photoId);
        sectorBoulderFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentId" + photoId)
                .commit();
```

4) I pass into a fragment, I take the entering photoId, on it in a database I look for a photo and I apply I insert it into imageView (xml).
Like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photos.get(0).getPhotoData(), 0, photos.get(0).getPhotoData().length);
```

fragmentPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

As a result when drawing I display only the last photo (on the first place). All others - simply a marking under it, the image isn't present.
Debug comes, puts down all values, correctly pulls out a photo from a DB.

Both images and points are added dynamically (different quantity).
I thought to make it in the adapter, but I don't represent as it normally to implement (Adapter (List) in adapter Image?)

Prompt the decision please.

Maybe in general it is necessary to do all on another.

Thx!

** there is no 10 reputation, what to add the image =((((

** I hope correctly explained

Comment: Image - https://habrastorage.org/files/687/6a4/7ad/6876a47ad29849deab3409eedfac28a6.jpg

Comment: structure of data such - Map<photoId, List<Item>>

Comment: Has done -> RecycleView in RecycleView.